# Каким образом реализовать подобную систему переписки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли и каким образом реализовать подобное:

На моем сайте пользователь может отправить сообщение другому пользователю, но это сообщение должно приходить не внутри сайта, а на email. - Это уже есть.

Когда приходит сообщение на почту, то email отправителя не должен быть виден, вместо него что угодно, рандомные символы например.
И после, если получатель письма отвечает на этот email, уже внутри самой почты(яндекс к примеру) , в таком случае становится видет обеим собеседникам емайлы, и они продолжают дальше вести переписку.

Возможно ли это, и каким образом?

P.S. - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Для чего:

> Алиасы: ты выдаешь произвольный набор символов для поля From емейла. Юзер отправляет сообщение, и вместо реального мыла приходит алиас. Если юзер посчитает нужным - он ответит, а сайт проверит на предмет фишинга, принадлежит ли алиас этому отправителю. То есть коммуникации защищены и спамер не узнает реальное мыло если юзер сам не ответит

Comment: Отправляя первому пользователю письмо со своего сервера указывайте в адресе возврата свой email на котором будет сидеть робот. Робот пусть пересылает это письмо (ответ) второму пользователю. Чтобы робот знал кому пересылать указывайте в адресе робота уникальный генерируемый идентификатор письма. Если email робота например `myrobot@gmail.com`, то можно делать так `myrobot+jhgjhuUUhfnjfj75858ndjdbash53544@gmail.com`. P.S. Спамеры таким способом с одного адреса могут кучу аккаунтов зарегить и спамить :)

Comment: @Visman а этого робота каким образом реализовать то?

Comment: Вам вариант в ответе предложили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути вам нужно развернуть почтовый сервис (например, Postfix), и обрабатывать входящую в него почту через php скрипт. В [этой статье описывается такая схема](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126448/)

> 1. Для начала убедитесь, что у вас есть работающий почтовый сервер.
>
> Можно сделать отдельный почтовик в поддомене, достаточно внести 2
>   записи в DNS:

```
rob.mydomain.ru. A ip-вашего-сервера 
rob.mydomain.ru. MX rob.mydomain.ru.
```

> 2. Отредактируйте файл с алиасами `/etc/aliases`: добавьте туда строку:
>      `robot: "|php -q /путь/к/скрипту.php"` `robot` — это название почтового
>      ящика; `/путь/к/скрипту.php` — скрипт обрабатывающий входящие.
>
> после редактирования выполните команду `newaliases`
>
> 3. в настройках `postfix` `main.cf` рекомендую добавить параметр:
>      `recipient_delimiter = +`
>
> тогда в адресе можно будет кодировать дополнительную
>   информацию:`robot+someId@rob.mydomain.ru`
>
> Все письма на такие адреса будет также обрабатывать наш скрипт. `someId`
>   может быть идентификатором пользователя или любыми другими данными.
>
> 4. создайте скрипт-обработчик писем:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Скрипт для автоматической обработки входящих писем
 *
 * Все данные smtp-конверта письма RECIPIENT, SENDER и другие postfix 
 * передает через окружение $_ENV; полный перечень переменных:
 * http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html секция EXTERNAL COMMAND DELIVERY 
 */

//текст сообщения считываем из STDIN
$msg = file_get_contents("php://stdin");

//отправитель письма
$sender = getenv('SENDER');

//получатель письма
$recipient = getenv('RECIPIENT');

//парсинг сообщения
list($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $msg, 2);

//выделим строки с Subject: и From:
$subject = '';
$from = '';
$headerArr = explode("\n", $header);
foreach ($headerArr as $str) {
  if (strpos($str, 'Subject:') === 0) {
    $subject = $str;
  }
  if (strpos($str, 'From:') === 0) {
    $from = $str;
  }
}

//для отладки сохраняем полученное сообщение в лог:
$logMsg = "=== MSG ===\n";
$logMsg .= "SENDER: $sender\n";
$logMsg .= "RECIPIENT: $recipient\n";
$logMsg .= "$from\n";
$logMsg .= "$subject\n\n";
$logMsg .= "$msg\n";
file_put_contents('/tmp/inb.log',$logMsg, FILE_APPEND);
```

Из сатьи А.Горлова: https://habrahabr.ru/post/126448/

Comment: Ну и скопировали бы статью сюда с указанием ссылки на оригинал.

Comment: Согласно правилам stackoverflow, [копирование чужих статей не приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @Crantisz так там и написано:  публикация чужих работ **без указания автора** – не одобряется....  значит с указанием можно)) Во всяком случае ссылка может устареть и умереть, и ответ станет бесполезным.... а с соблюдением правил и указанием источника и автора, ответ хоть какую-то значимость будет иметь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну ок